# What are the uses and benefits of entity classes?

Tags: php, class, oop, entity

I often come across code like the following (reference [Slim tutorial](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/tutorial/first-app.html) at [github](https://github.com/slimphp/Tutorial-First-Application)).

TicketMapper.php

```
class TicketMapper extends Mapper
{
    public function getTickets() {
        $sql = "SELECT t.id, t.title, t.description, c.component
            from tickets t
            join components c on (c.id = t.component_id)";
        $stmt = $this->db->query($sql);
        $results = [];
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $results[] = new TicketEntity($row);
        }
        return $results;
    }
    /**
     * Get one ticket by its ID
     *
     * @param int $ticket_id The ID of the ticket
     * @return TicketEntity  The ticket
     */
    public function getTicketById($ticket_id) {
        $sql = "SELECT t.id, t.title, t.description, c.component
            from tickets t
            join components c on (c.id = t.component_id)
            where t.id = :ticket_id";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stmt->execute(["ticket_id" => $ticket_id]);
        if($result) {
            return new TicketEntity($stmt->fetch());
        }
    }
    public function save(TicketEntity $ticket) {
        $sql = "insert into tickets
            (title, description, component_id) values
            (:title, :description, 
            (select id from components where component = :component))";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stmt->execute([
            "title" => $ticket->getTitle(),
            "description" => $ticket->getDescription(),
            "component" => $ticket->getComponent(),
        ]);
        if(!$result) {
            throw new Exception("could not save record");
        }
    }
}
```

TicketEntity.php

```
class TicketEntity
{
    protected $id;
    protected $title;
    protected $description;
    protected $component;
    /**
     * Accept an array of data matching properties of this class
     * and create the class
     *
     * @param array $data The data to use to create
     */
    public function __construct(array $data) {
        // no id if we're creating
        if(isset($data['id'])) {
            $this->id = $data['id'];
        }
        $this->title = $data['title'];
        $this->description = $data['description'];
        $this->component = $data['component'];
    }
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }
    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }
    public function getShortDescription() {
        return substr($this->description, 0, 20);
    }
    public function getComponent() {
        return $this->component;
    }
}
```

My current practice does not use the entity classes and my mapper methods just return a stdClass such as shown below:

```
class TicketMapper extends Mapper
{
    public function getTickets() {
        $sql = "...";
        $stmt = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    public function getTicketById($ticket_id) {
        $sql = "...";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stmt->execute(["ticket_id" => $ticket_id]);
        return $stmt->fetch();  //Assuming my PDO is configured to return an object only
    }
    public function save($ticket) {/* no change */}
}
```

Why are the database results often wrapped in some entity class?  Is there any criteria which one would determine whether or not to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) is to act as persistence layer between your business logic and your storage. It populates or store data in entity objects.

And those entities have several goals:

- encapsulation: you have ability to track and control how the data, that entities contain, is accessed and altered
- validation: ensuring that the state of the entity matches the business rules and ability to detect, if the entity has entered (or is about to enter) an invalid state
- contracts: you can use typehints to define what other modules (classes, functions) can use this entity and what types of things it can accept as parameters. You also get an option to define what interface a substitute of this entity has to implement
- behavior: an entity will often have associated behavior (or business logic), as an example: `$article->markAsApproved()` operation will not be a trivial setter but instead make an atomic change of state.

As for criteria ... well ... "are you using OOP or not" would be closest one. The `stdClass` is just a glorified array with no behavior.

You probably should watch [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHBrDWIKW8Q).

Comment: Thanks tereško,  I actually did see some benefit of validation and contracts (however, I thought the service and not the entity should be responsible responsible for validation).  Just saw your behavior goal pop up which I guess makes sense.  Do you always do so unless you have some compelling reason not to?  Watching the lecture right now.

Comment: The validation is a very vague term :( because it actually covers different types of things. For example "does the email address look correct" would be validated by entity, while "has someone already registered this email" would be done in a mapper (because it would be a data integrity check). And things like "can you start a checkout with 0 items in the shopping cart" would be something, that is checked by a service.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation: A class is a useful packet containing the code and the relevant data together, isolated from everything else. That makes it easier to move it around without searching for exact variables, without collisions with existing code/data.

Of course classes have other uses but in scripting environments like PHP, I think the biggest advantage is that.

Code reuse

Inheritance

Easier maintainability

etc. Do some research its a funny thing to learn

Comment: Thanks gmbc.  I definitely see the benefits of classes, reduced script through inheritance, and encapsulation, but never see any functionality implemented with these entity classes other than a couple of getters and setters which makes me question why bother using them.